# Why use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() instead of isInterrupted()?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a question regarding the implementation of a cancellation policy for a Thread subclass. It seems to be common practice to do it like this:

```
class A extends Thread {

  [...]

  public final void run() {
     try {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
           [...]
        }
     } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
     }
  }

  public final void cancel() {
     interrupt();
  }    
}
```

The question I have is regarding Thread.currentThread()... Why is it common practice to use currentThread() for checking the interruption flag but not for setting it in the cancel() method? Wouldn't it suffice to just call the isInterrupted() method of A like this:

```
while (!isInterrupted()) {
   [...]
}
```

I couldn't find an answer neither in the Thread JavaDoc, Brian Goetz' excellent book on concurrent Java or stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Cheers,
Georg

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your case it is sufficient to just call `!isInterrupted()` because you're extending from the `Thread` class. Typically you don't extend from `Thread` - that's why you call `Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: I get your point. When implementing a Task using the Runnable interface, using Thread.isInterrupted() makes total sense to me, too. I still wonder why the coding examples I've seen in "Java Concurrency in Practice" which also extended Thread used Thread.currentThread(). I have a hunch that there is a reason for that.

Comment: @BumbleGee Maybe it's just a matter of copy-paste or constistency throught the examples. I don't know that book but if there are examples using `Runnable` as well, then I suspect it's one of these two, most likely the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Java 5 it is [not a good idea to work with Threads directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597331/difference-between-multithreading-with-and-without-executor) . You should rather use Executor framework and choose an execution policy depending on your requirements .  The instance `isInterrupted()` method tests whether this thread has been interrupted. The interrupted status of the thread is unaffected by this method.The inner `isInterrupted()` is actually a native method .

```
906     public boolean isInterrupted() {
907         return isInterrupted(false);
908     }
```

While using the executor framework you do not know which thread instance is executing your code currently  and hence the convention is to use Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()

Comment: thanks for your hint. We are using the Executor framework in other places, too, and have come to like it.

Answer (score 2):

The `cancel` is clear: it's effectively directing the call to `this.interrupt`; i.e the Thread instance to which the `cancel` method is applied.

As for the `run` method, everything you state make sense on the assumption that the `run` method was actually called, and only called, by the (expected) instance of `class A`.  While that's likely a safe assumption, is it universally true?  Now if you're going to ask me for a meaningful example of how/when that assumption *might* be violated, not sure I can pull that out of my hat this late at night :-)

Consider a method other than `run`.  If it's a method on `class A` should it assume it's being called by/on the same thread?  Maybe it's a method on another class.  So it seems likely this is just a best-practice to eliminate potential bugs: your code becomes copy/paste-proof [@Thomas made this insight as well]

Answer (score 1):

It should be same, IF that code is is in currently running thread.
Maybe authors fear, that someone will execute run method in other thread, maybe they want it look same as awerywhere else.
Or they copy pasted it and did not think.